# jQuery UI Datepicker - Month and Year Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the [**following Datepicker**](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year) on my website.

As you can see from the example they have, it only goes as back as 2006 and as forward as 2026 on the year. I need the year to go back a lot further, how would I accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#passenger_dob").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Once you select 2006 as the year , the range of the selection becomes 1996 - 2016 .So you can keep going back by selecting the lowest year

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

Comment: Hi there, I understand that but this is not what I want. I want the years up to around the 1930s to be on the drop down straight away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the yearRange option to set the years you want do display:

```
$("#passenger_dob").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true, 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    yearRange: "-90:+00"
});
```

the yearRange options can be hard-coded, or, as in my example, a range can be used relative to the current date. The options I've used mean "earliest year displayed is 90 years before current year" and "maximum year displayed is equal to current year".

N.B. As noted in the docs, this merely affects the options displayed in the dropdown by default, it doesn't place any restriction on the dates which the user can actually enter/select.

See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the help!